# Make link bold if column is visible (not hidden)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, show-hide

I have a filter menu which I put inside a table, and when one of the links are clicked, the according column in another separate table becomes hidden, until the link is click on again.

```
<!-- Table for filter menu -->
    <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">hideColumn1</a> |
              <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2">hideColumn2</a> |
              <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3">hideColumn3</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      <table>

<script>
    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );=
</script>
```

**My aim is to have some way of showing which columns are hidden/shown**, so onClick, I would like the link text to become bold or change color or whatever. 
Do I need to loop through my table? I have no idea - very new to HTML so any help is appreciated and the getElementById doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Could you make a working example of your code (what you have so far) in jsfiddle or codepen or some other place? This would make it easier to help you.

Comment: I'm having problems making a jsfiddle example, I'll keep trying though! @thepio

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution and thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` in order to get the clicked element, and then modify its inline-styling based on that (or use a class).

### Inline styling

```
<!-- Table for filter menu -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">hideColumn1</a> |
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2">hideColumn2</a> |
      <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3">hideColumn3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>

<script>
  $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ADDED CODE
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.css('font-weight') === 'bold') {
      element.css({
        'font-weight': 'normal'
      });
    } else {
      element.css({
        'font-weight': 'bold'
      });
    }
    // END OF ADDED CODE
    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  } );=
</script>
```

### Classes

With classes, this is even simpler. Add this to your style:

```
.bold-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and then, just use this function:

```
<script>
  $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ADDED CODE
    var element = $(this);
    element.toggleClass('bold-link');
    // END OF ADDED CODE
    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  } );=
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a bunch! @Thatkookooguy

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the last clicked link (and remove previous class).
At the beginning of your file.

```
<style>
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

In the function

```
$('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Also why are you calling `e.preventDefault()`?
Is it for when you click the link to not do anything?
Another way is to give a `href=""` attribute to the links and to `return false` at the end of the `onclick` function.

Comment: This would assume that only 1 column is hidden at any one time. What would happen if more than one column were to be hidden? In that case, its probably better to use `$(this).toggleClass('selected')`. Though the OP doesn't make it clear if more that 1 column is hidden at any one point

Comment: When not providing a `href` attribute some browsers might behave differently (e.g. treating the `<a>` tag as simple text. This could also be part of some non-script fallback to switch pages.